# Jquery - How to store checked items in html form and return it in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

imagine we have got some page like this:

```
<button id="del"><i  class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></button>

<input type="checkbox" class="del_list" value="1"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="del_list" value="2"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="del_list" value="3"/>
```

Now I want to build a `jquery` function which can enable me to store values of `del_list` class if the checkbox is checked. I want this function to be triggered by clicking on the `del` button.

I developed jquery function like this but it does not work.

```
$("#del").click(function ()
{
  vals = [];
  $(".del_list").each(function ()
  {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      vals.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
  alert(vals);
});
```

I want to send `vals` array to a php form to delete the checked contents in my work. if there is any other answer or solution with as few changes as possible in `php` or `javascript`, please let me know.

thanks a lot for your helps

Comment: you have to use ajax.

Comment: What "does not work" - do you get an array of vals successfully..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#del").click(function ()
    {
      data = [];
      $(".del_list").each(function ()
      {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
          data.push($(this).val());
        }
      });
      console.log(data);
      var url="http://localhost:8090";
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: data,
          success: function(response){
          console.log("succes");
          },
          error: function(response){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
          }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="del">delete</button>
<input type="checkbox" class="del_list" value="1"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="del_list" value="2"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="del_list" value="3"/>
```

Try this
Use `$.ajax` calls to communicate with `php`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value in to a hidden field and submit it.

Html

```
<input type="hidden" id="del_list" name="del_list" />
```

And javascript will be:

```
$("#del").click(function ()
{
  vals = [];
  $(".del_list").each(function ()
  {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      vals.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
  $('#del_list').val(vals);
});
```

Now the hidden field contains the deleted list value as comma separated value list

Comment: The idea is valuable to me. thanks for spending time for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself is working so i guess you missed to include jQuery.

```js
$("#del").click(function ()
{
  vals = [];
  $(".del_list").each(function ()
  {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      vals.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
  alert(vals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="del">delete</button>
<input type="checkbox" class="del_list" value="1"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="del_list" value="2"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="del_list" value="3"/>
```